# How to use \url in \fancyhead

Tags: fancyhdr, urls

I have text like the following in my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\overfullrule}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\fontsize{10}{12} \url{github.com/temp/long-url-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-temp.pdf}.  \\\ \selectfont \it{This study has not been peer reviewed.}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{42 pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{Example Document for SO Question}
\end{document}
```

In the resultant pdf (see below), the url is being broken onto multiple lines and is not clickable. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Make a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test.

Comment: Please improve your MWE and make it compilable (starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`). Please also delete all unnecessary (and repeated) packages/commands which are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I have done this.

Comment: I get a pdf with the url clickable and directs to the right link, if given an existing long url. Hence I cannot reproduce your problem. Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: Thank you @muzimuzhiZ., you pointed me in the right direction, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Skim to preview the pdf produced by Latex, then produced another pdf by using the Skim menu sequence `Print/PDF/Open in Preview`. The resultant Skim produced pdf had the url broken. However, if I just opened the original pdf produced by Latex, the url works fine.  Thank you to @muzimuzhiZ's comment which pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and assign a `\pagestyle`? I just copied and compiled (assuming standard article) and everything looks fine, nothing broken, and the links are clickable.

[image]

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\fontsize{10}{12} \url{https://github.com/temp/long-url-temp.pdf}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added all the first part of the document, and have augmented the url so it should be sufficiently long that it goes over one line.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I couldn't understand what is the problem of breaking long url into more than one line when the url is already longer than one line? Do you mean the displayed text of the url rather than the url link itself? For example, do you want to display a short text like "click here" which points to a long url link?